# Matlab error in multiplication

Tags: matlab

this may be an utterly stupid question but I cannot multiply two variables in matlab. I don't know what I am doing wrong.Here's the command window:

```
>> a(200,200)

ans =

  255

>> a(200,200)*255

ans =

  255
```

shouldn't the answer of be 65025? obviously I cannot understand what I am doing wrong in this simple example.
Thx in advance

Comment: Try `class(a)` my guess is it says `uint8` or something like that. try instead `double(a(200,200))*255`

Comment: @JensBoldsen yes you are right. Why does it happens? Aren't they both ints?

Comment: Yes, but `uint8` variables only holds 8 bits of data; that is any number from 0 to 255. There is space for the values `inf`, `nan` or `-inf` so if you get a value outside the scope, it will either give you `0` or `255`.

Comment: @JensBoldsen Thx a lot for your explanation. Write down the answer to mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem: `uint8`.

`uint8` is a class for holding integers between `0` and `255`. Most operations between elements of the class `uint8` will give a result in the class `uint8`, since not all numbers are in the interval of integers between `0` and `255` you do cannot rely on the answer being correct, instead you get the answer closest to being correct. In your case you get `255`.